# Como manter SDK e JRE Java instalados e atualizados em um ambiente windows de desenvolvimento

Tags: java, windows, sdk

Como manter uma instalação java(SDK e JRE) segura, limpa e atualizada do Java em um computador usado para desenvolvimento de software?

Estou com problemas para manter meu ambiente de desenvolvimento, pois tenho as IDE's Eclipse e Android Studio instaladas, assim como algumas outras aplicações que usam o java, e hoje tive um problema enorme após uma atualização do Java, o path nas variáveis do Windows começaram a apontar para pastas que não eram as corretas, e ai Eclipse e o Android Studio param de funcionar, depois ajustei isso e o Tomcat se perdeu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não sei existe alguma outra maneira de as variável de ambiente de forma mais prática, fiz um script em powershell para automatizar esse processo.

**Limitações:**

- Sua variável de ambiente precisa ter o nome de  `JAVA_HOME` caso seja outro nome é necessário substituir as ocorrencias de `JAVA_HOME` pelo nome da sua variável.
- Algumas instalações do java não possuem o local de instação logo elas não serão exibidas.

---

```
clear
write-host "Aguarde..."
[object[]]$r =  (Get-WmiObject win32_product -Filter " name like 'JAVA %'")

$javaHome = "JAVA_HOME"

Write-Host "Valor atual do JAVA_HOME: $env:JAVA_HOME `n"

$opcao = 0
$itensValidos = @()
foreach($item in $r){
    if($item.InstallLocation -ne $null){
          Write-Host $opcao - $item.Name - $item.InstallLocation
          $itensValidos += $item
          $opcao++
    }
}

$selecionado = Read-Host "`nInforme qual instalação do java será definida em JAVA_HOME"


if($selecionado -lt 0 -or $selecionado -gt $itensValidos.Count -1){
   Write-Host "Opção invalida"
} 

[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable($javaHome, $itensValidos[$selecionado].InstallLocation +"lib" , 'Machine')
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Funcionamento**

É feita a pesquisa de todos os softwares instalados que possuem `JAVA` nome, as linhas seguintes exibem o menu com as instalações válidas do java (aquelas que tem o caminho da insalação), depois é feita solicitação de será o nome caminho de `JAVA_HOME` e por último é feita a mudanção com o método `SetEnvironmentVariable()`.

Fontes:

[Windows PowerShell Tip of the Week](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730964.aspx)

[Classe Environment .net](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z46c489x%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1)

[Get-WmiObject](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849824.aspx)

Comment: Só um adendo, tive que tirar o 'lib' do final dessa linha aqui [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable($javaHome, $itensValidos[$selecionado].InstallLocation **+"lib"** , 'Machine') 
para funcionar corretamente, o android studio dizia que não encontrava uma versão válida da JVM, e passando o path para a pasta de instalação, exemplo: 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_55\' funcionou

Comment: @alexandre werner, obrigado pela correção vou editar depois.